# How/When/Where do you set headers when using Puppeteer with a proxy to request an HTTPS site?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am running into an issue when using a headless browser in puppeteer.

I need to set a header for a proxy that I am routing through. This is not an issue. Puppeteer has a method .setExtraHTTPHeaders() that makes this very easy.

However, if the page I am requesting is using HTTPS (in most of my cases it is) then my proxy will never see this header because it will obviously be encrypted by the time it passes through.

Is this even possible to accomplish and if so how?

Below is a simple example I've been using. If I request the httpbin.org/ip site with *http* then it works perfectly. If I request it with *https* then it works but my header gets lost in the middle and doesn't do its job.

```
                const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
                    headless: true,
                    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
                    args: [
                        '--no-sandbox',
                        `--proxy-server=my.proxy.url:00000`
                    ]
                });

                const page = await browser.newPage();

                await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
                    'SOME_HEADER_TO_SET': 'VALUE'
                });

                await page.goto('https://httpbin.org/ip');
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add the authentication to be passed in the proxy URL instead?

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    args: [
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--proxy-server=username:password@my.proxy.url:00000'
        ]
    });
```

Comment: Try this one also:
https://blog.apify.com/how-to-make-headless-chrome-and-puppeteer-use-a-proxy-server-with-authentication-249a21a79212

Comment: Authentication is not the issue. I am having problems with other custom headers getting overlooked.